# Laravel 4.2 - "message":"Undefined index: timezone" .. in src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/start.php","line":167

Tags: datetime, laravel

This started popping up last week and has killed a project which is two months into development.  I can guarantee that the datetime.timezone value *is* set. WTH? This kind of instability is enough to make me abandon Laravel and possibly start bad mouthing it.

This exception is being thrown every time I try to run artisan commands, or more precisely (I think) when artisan attempts to rebuild the autoload files.

"message":"Undefined index: timezone" .. in src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php","line":167

Any help appreciated.

Comment: And did you open up `src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php` and look on line `167` to see whats happening?

Comment: Yes. Illuminate is setting the timezone into the default php.ini variable.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might need to specify your timezone, the line in question:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src%2FIlluminate%2FFoundation%2Fstart.php#L167

In my Laravel 4.2 app, in `app/config/app.php` I have:

```
'timezone' => 'UTC
```

If you dont have that key/value pair, try setting it. In this case Laravel wants this specifically set and wont bother to check your PHP ini datetime/timezone setting.

Comment: That would be exactly why I put this line in the original post:  ' I can guarantee that the datetime.timezone value is set.'

Comment: But `datetime.timezone` is a `php.ini` construct, not a Laravel config construct, which is WHY that error is being thrown. Because the array key doesn't exist. It appears you can specify it in `php.ini` all you want but until its in the Laravel config it doesnt mean squat.